# Suggestions on why site is slow/how to speed up?

Tags: wordpress, performance

I know the website is very image based, I have limited plugins as much as I can and compressed CSS and styling. It shouldn't be as slow as it is. Any reason why this or what I can do to speed it up? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my opinion

1- you are using too much css and javascript
2- Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content
3- you should optimize your image
4- you can upgrade your server to faster server
5- Enable compression and browser caching
and .....

EDIT:
how improve above steps:
1- for better performance its better to keep page size under 600kbit usually it's because of theme or the plugin we use, then if you can, change your template to an optimize version and reduce your unnecessary plugins. on the other hand there are some features that can handle by just few codes, but we rather to install a new plugin so new plugins has its self javascript and css
2-put all your javascript codes on the footer befoter `</body>` ([help](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS)), and create a javascript loader for your css, that insert your css on the head.([help](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery)) simple example of render-blocking

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- do not insert css or javascript here -->
</head>
<body>
<!--
 #################
    contents
#################
 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dis/cssloader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dis/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and your cssloader

```
//cssloader.js
var version = "?v1";
var cb = function() {
    var styles = [
        "/dist/custom1.min.css",
        "/dist/custom1.min.css",
    ];
    var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < styles.length; i++) {
        var l = document.createElement('link');
        l.rel = 'stylesheet';
        l.href = styles[i]+version;
        h.appendChild(l);
    }
};
var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame || webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;
if (raf) raf(cb);
else window.addEventListener('load', cb);
```

3- optimizing image means to reduce your image scale as you can, and saved your images for web (if your are using photoshop it has an option to do this, it's obvious that it reduce your images quality )

4-sometime just some configuration on server , improve it's performance
5- if your are using apache, you should add some line of codes on your apache config so that comperssion and caching enable for it, you can do this by `.htaccess` too ([help](http://www.giftofspeed.com/enable-gzip-compression/))([help](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/speed-up-sites-with-htaccess-caching.html))

Comment: thanks for the tips. images are already being optimized with wp smush, and even when I remove my custom css it really does not make a difference. the website is already on  a dedicated server as well. what is render-block script and how I can remove? and do you know which js is causing issues? thanks

Comment: @JohnB. do you user apache o nginx?

Comment: pretty sure its apache

Comment: @JohnB. a explain more on the answer

Comment: thanks. if i do the .htaccess caching should i still use a caching plugin?

Comment: @JohnB. not actually , I recommend no use any plugin for this king on things.plugins usually not work well for this things

Comment: okay thanks for your help. any advice on removing the render blocking js? will take all other points into consideration

Comment: @JohnB. i add an example for render-blocking

Comment: in the cssloader would i include just my theme css or all css files? also would i replace <script type="text/javascript" src="/dis/scripts.js"></script> with all js files (including plugins) or just theme js files? thanks!

Comment: @JohnB. on cssloader should include all your css files, and inside script, should add all scripts files at the bottom of your websites

Answer (score 1):

This suffers from a grotesque amount of Javascript and CSS. Minifying them into a single file each or at least consistently using their minified versions will help, but at *7.1MB* for a single page, including a 1.1MB image, you might consider that you're doing something fundamentally wrong regarding page design and use of images. Even on a fast desktop this is slow, and even with minified styles and scripts (and resized, not just 'optimized', images), on mobile it'll (still) be unusable.

Edit: That size is with ghostery enabled, so it's likely a bit on the low side, and those won't do anything to help your load time.

Comment: thanks for the tips. the site is updated daily by djs who pull images off the net. i will have to advise them to use resize their images or re-save them to get smaller size. i am working on removing all unnecessary css and js.do you have any other tips for me? thanks

Comment: If you know the max size your images should be, it shouldn't be too hard to resize them on the fly so no human intervention is required (I know how nasty it can get when you have to give your users too much freedom with content). Definitely look into minified versions of things like libraries, and possibly a [minification library like this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bwp-minify/) (I can't personally recommend this or any other one, never having used one for WP, but the concept is what's important).